# Do we have different editions of WAS 7

Tags: java, websphere

Do we have different editions in WAS 7 like WAS Developer edition and WAS Enterprise edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many editions, as with the other versions of Websphere.

You can find a matrix of the features here - http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/wasproductline/compare.html

An overview of the different editions are

- Network Deployment
- for z/OS
- Application Server
- Community Edition
- Express
- Hypervisor Edition

Comment: @Erloewe Can u pls tell me how to accept it. I mean is there a button in the forum to mark it accepted.

Comment: There should be a little tick next to the answer. Click it and it will turn green.